# How to use only Tomcat's shared lib folder?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, deployment, war

I have learned that we can add a `.jar` library inside a context's `WEB_INF\lib` folder to make that library accessible only to that context or at `CATALINA_HOME\lib` folder to make that library accessible for all my applications running on that Tomcat instance.

I wanted to drop my jdbc driver library on Tomcat's shared library folder `CATALINA_HOME\lib` so all my applications could use it and also take advantage of Tomcat's connection pooling, but I having some issues.

I am using NetBeans as my IDE and I have to define my jdbc driver on NetBeans so it will compile my code using the driver. But when NetBeans compiled my code for deployment in a `.war` it automatically places my driver `.jar` at the `WEB_INF\lib` folder inside the `.war`.

**How can I avoid NetBeans from embedding my library on the `.war` archive so I can take advantage of Tomcat's shared library folder?**

Comment: You don't need to have the driver in the compile classpath, since you're only using (or at least you should only be using) classes from than java.sql and javax.sql package. The compiler doesn't need the driver. You only need it at runtime.

Comment: I am using some specific MySQL classes to identify some exceptions on the database and react accordingly... But right now I tested removing that code and the library and my application isn't finding my jar on tomcat apparently...

Comment: What are you using as a build tool? Gradle? Maven? None?

Comment: Default NetBeans configuration, no special setup environment for this project so far, so no build tools or anything (but I think NetBeans uses maven under the hood)

Comment: In the project properties, under Libraries, the list of libraries has a "package" checkbox next to every library. I guess if you uncheck it, the library won't be packaged with the app.

Comment: Good call! I will test it when I am back home, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by  JB Nizet:

> In the project properties, under Libraries, the list of libraries has a "package" >checkbox next to every library. I guess if you uncheck it, the library won't be >packaged with the app.